# Metadata Rejected, do i need to resubmit the app ??

Tags: ios, metadata

Apple asked me the information about the app and status changed from "In Review" to "Metadata Rejected". I provided them with the information they asked and clicked on "Submit for review" again.
After 8 days they again rejected it asked another set of information.

This time i provided them with the information but didn't clicked on "Submit for Review" button.

After 3 days they replied that thank for the information and we will continue to review you app. Now its been 10 days they didn't replied anything nor even the status of app changed.

What shall i do, do i need to click on "Submit for review" or just wait for them to reply. Its been one and half month i uploaded the binary.

Kindly help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 6):

For those who are not sure what to do because answers are quite old this is what I do in **September 2019**.

I got a Metadata rejected (some screenshot issue): **do not click on submit for review** just make the necessary changes and save your data. After that, reply to the reviewer using The Resolution Center saying that you've just done the changes. Then just wait (an hour or a little more). They will review again that part that it was wrong. Is the best way to get the approval ASAP

Comment: While this may be the officially requested way, I've only once had the app go back into review after a reasonable time span (faster than re-submitting). And only once I've gotten a reply in the resolution center (I've fixed issues and replied in a matter of minutes). These days, it takes almost only 24h to get your app in review so I always just re-submit. If Apply don't want that, they should keep that button locked.

Answer (score 5):

After a metadata rejection, your will receive an email with a link to the Resolution Center. Make the necessary changes and save your app **(don't click on "Submit for Review" button).**

Send a message to your reviewer using the Resolution Center and wait a few hours. Your app will be "In Review" soon. Also you can "Submit an Appeal to the Apple Review Team".

**Update:** My application was submitted **January 7, 2016** Rejected by Metadata on **January 13, 2016**. I received a message from Apple: "Once you have brought your app into compliance regarding this issue, we can continue with review of your app". After send a message to the reviewer using the Resolution Center (Hello Apple, I made the necessary changes to my app), The status changes "In Review" after 60 mins.

Answer (score 1):

you could Contact the App Review Team and request an expedited app review.https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=expedite. call APPLE or.

Comment: Thanks ZhangYong, I made a request. Do u know how long they will take to respond ??

Comment: I took four days this time. and you?

Comment: Now it takes one day only after releasing few versions

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, do NOT click the `submit for review` button! Even, with a metadata reject, it will put you at the end of the review queue and you'll have to wait another 6-8 days (or whatever the current wait time is).

I would message them again and ask for an update on the review.

Usually you can fix the metadata and message Apple though the resolution center. In my experience, the reviewer has always approved the app. The wait can be as little as an hour or as long as a couple of days, but it's always been faster than the review queue, and you're getting the same reviewer.

Answer (score -4):

Yes you need to press button `Submit for review` to move your app to the review queue

Comment: Thanks for the response azat but this guy is saying don't click http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/

Also i have seen many places saying that don't click.